# Asynchronous chaining in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynccallback

I have been trying to get a not so sophisticated solution to chaining and this is what I came up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/mithun_daa/fEGsj/2/

It seems to work but when I have multiple calls to "myapp":

```
//call the success callback
$('#ph').text(window.myapp.doWork(true).success(onSuccess).error(onSuccess));
//call the error callback
$('#ph').text(window.myapp.doWork(false).success(onSuccess).error(onError));
```

the callback is immediately called. I am trying to find a vanilla JS solution. I know jQuery provides promises but I was just curious to see how I would do it in pure JS.

Comment: your async call is NOT appending the returned value of the success/error callbacks to the div, fyi. That simply isn't possible in a chain with asynchronous methods.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that and I am not logging it to the console instead. That was a left over from something I was trying earlier. I updated the fiddle and the link to it to reflect the changes.

Comment: Ah, sorry. As far as what's in the fiddle, since both cases have a delay of 2 seconds, it makes sense for them both to occur at the same time (which is what i'm seeing). What exactly is the question? http://jsfiddle.net/fEGsj/4/ your code seems to work as-is

Comment: Maybe it is just my poor understanding of setTimeout, but I assumed that when the second call is made, there would be a pause for another 2 secs. Will that not be the case? Will this work just fine if a true ajax call is made?

Comment: Correct, that will not be the case. Since you started them both at the same time with the same delay, they will finish at the same time. The same will be true for ajax, just keep in mind that the ajax requests will not always finish in the same order that they start.

Comment: If you wanted the second doWork() call to start when the first finishes, you would need to start in in the success handler of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is so ubiquitous that there is an entire community to solve it http://www.promisejs.org
Will be folded in to future release of js.